# Restrict pages a anonymous user can view in Django

Tags: django

I am creating a website that has a flow that consists of about 7 pages. The user can only navigate to page1 of the flow if they have a specific url which looks like..

```
domain.com/flow/home/uid=123
```

The UID gets checked in my models to see if it exists and if it does, they get to view the correct page1. If it does not exist then they get redirected to another page. I want to make sure that they can navigate to page2 but only if they are allowed. I have 2 ideas which not sure if is the correct way or if another better way exists.

1. Set a request variable to 'allowed' and check it on every page. If it isn't set then redirect them back to home.
2. Pass the uid in the URL and make sure it is valid on every page.

I am leaning towards option 1 as it is easier/cleaner but I wanted to check if any other solutions exist.

Comment: `domain.com/flow/home/uid=123` or `domain.com/flow/home/?uid=123`?

Comment: The first one. I don't need a question mark in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom user model and there you can have a property allowed. Then check if the request.user.allowed condition to proceed to page2.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/